# Possibility of memory leak in method

Tags: java

This is my method, I want to know if there is possibility for memory leak? If there is what should I do to?

```
private byte[] getNewContent(String filePath, int position, int size) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    file.seek(position);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion, if possible run a sonar analysis https://www.sonarqube.org/ on your code

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is resource leak

if some exception happens in seek/read methods - file will not be closed, it is better to use try-with-resources idiom:

```
private byte[] getNewContent(String filePath, int position, int size) throws IOException {
    try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r")) {
        file.seek(position);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        file.read(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

this way file will be closed no matter what

Comment: Thank is good answer. Than you very much.